# Receiving data from USRP

Tags: c++, gnuradio, usrp

I have written a small c++ program that receives data from the USRP. The program can receive the I/Q data and show it on a spectrum analyzer. The receiver LED is not always green though. It sorts of blinking and dimming. I suspect there is a rate mismatch between the computer and the USRP. Could this be the case? How does one make sure that the computer consumes the samples at the same rate as the USRP is acquiring them? Below is a thread function I use for the I/Q signal acquisition.

```
void
USRPDriver::RxEventLoop()
{
    uhd::rx_metadata_t md;
    uhd::stream_cmd_t stream_cmd(uhd::stream_cmd_t::STREAM_MODE_NUM_SAMPS_AND_DONE);
    stream_cmd.stream_now = true;
    stream_cmd.num_samps = 1024;
    //std::cout << "Maximum num samps = " << rx_stream->get_max_num_samps() << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::complex<float> > fcpxIQ;
    fcpxIQ.resize(1024);
    usrp->issue_stream_cmd(stream_cmd);
    while(true)
    {
        usrp->issue_stream_cmd(stream_cmd);
        size_t num_rx_samps = rx_stream->recv(&fcpxIQ[0], 1024, md);
        emit ReceiveIQ(fcpxIQ);
        //std::cout << "Rx rate = " << usrp->get_rx_rate(0) << std::endl;
        //fcpxIQ.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you get `O` or `S` or `D` printed to your console?

Comment: NUM_SAMPS_AND_DONE doesnt print the O/S/D. STREAM_MODE_NUM_SAMPS_AND_MORE works for a while but then it starts printing a trail of Os. However, the trail stops when I disable the spectrum analyzer function (with FFTs and plotting functions). So should  STREAM_MODE_NUM_SAMPS_AND_MORE be the option to use for continuous streaming?

Comment: yes, exactly. And the fact that it prints O means your PC is not fast enough at processing the samples.

Answer (score 0):

you should **not** use `NUM_SAMPS_AND_DONE` if you want continuous streaming. That's exactly *not* the use case it's for: It tells the USRP to stop receiving once 1024 samples have been received.

Simply don't use that mode.